# bash: choose default from case when enter is pressed in a "select" prompt

Tags: bash, user-input, interactive

I'm prompting questions in a bash script like this:

```
optionsAudits=("Yep" "Nope")
    echo "Include audits?"
    select opt in "${optionsAudits[@]}"; do
        case $REPLY in
            1) includeAudits=true; break ;;
            2) includeAudits=false; break ;;
            "\n") echo "You pressed enter"; break ;; # <--- doesn't work
            *) echo "What's that?"; exit;;
        esac
    done
```

How can I select a default option when enter is pressed? The `"\n"` case does not catch the enter key.

Comment: An aside to future readers: The body of the `select` statement is unusual, because it examines the raw user input - `$REPLY` - rather than the `select` statement's output variable, `$opt` (which contains the chosen option's _text_, not the _index_).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To complement [Aserre's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42790075/45375), which explains the problem with your code and offers an effective workaround, with **background information and a generic, reusable custom `select` implementation that allows empty input**:

---

#### Background information

To spell it out explicitly: **`select` *itself* ignores empty input** (just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and **simply re-prompts** - user code doesn't even get to run in response.

In fact, **`select` uses the empty string to signal to user code that an *invalid* choice was typed**.
That is, if the output variable - `$opt`, int this case - is *empty* inside the `select` statement, the implication is that an invalid choice index was typed by the user.

The **output variable receives the chosen option's *text*** - either `'Yep'` or `'Nope'` in this case - **not the *index*** typed by the user.

(By contrast, your code examines `$REPLY` instead of the output variable, which contains exactly what the user typed, which *is* the *index* in case of a valid choice, but may contain extra leading and trailing whitespace).

Note that **in the event that you *didn't* want to allow empty input**, you could
simply indicate to the user in the prompt text that **`^C` (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) can be used to abort the prompt**.

---

#### Generic custom `select` function that also accepts empty input

The following function closely emulates what `select` does while also allowing empty input (just pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>). Note that the function intercepts invalid input, prints a warning, and re-prompts:

```
# Custom `select` implementation that allows *empty* input.
# Pass the choices as individual arguments.
# Output is the chosen item, or "", if the user just pressed ENTER.
# Example:
#    choice=$(selectWithDefault 'one' 'two' 'three')
selectWithDefault() {

  local item i=0 numItems=$# 

  # Print numbered menu items, based on the arguments passed.
  for item; do         # Short for: for item in "$@"; do
    printf '%s\n' "$((++i))) $item"
  done >&2 # Print to stderr, as `select` does.

  # Prompt the user for the index of the desired item.
  while :; do
    printf %s "${PS3-#? }" >&2 # Print the prompt string to stderr, as `select` does.
    read -r index
    # Make sure that the input is either empty or that a valid index was entered.
    [[ -z $index ]] && break  # empty input
    (( index >= 1 && index <= numItems )) 2>/dev/null || { echo "Invalid selection. Please try again." >&2; continue; }
    break
  done

  # Output the selected item, if any.
  [[ -n $index ]] && printf %s "${@: index:1}"

}
```

You could call it as follows:

```
# Print the prompt message and call the custom select function.
echo "Include audits (default is 'Nope')?"
optionsAudits=('Yep' 'Nope')
opt=$(selectWithDefault "${optionsAudits[@]}")

# Process the selected item.
case $opt in
  'Yep') includeAudits=true; ;;
  ''|'Nope') includeAudits=false; ;; # $opt is '' if the user just pressed ENTER
esac
```

**Alternative implementation** that **lets the function itself handle the default logic**:<sup>Thanks, [RL-S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11770674/rl-s)</sup>

This implementation differs from the above in two respects:

- It allows you to designate a default among the choices, by prefixing it with `!`, with the *first* choice becoming the default otherwise. The default choice is printed with a trailing  `[default]` (and without the leading `!`). The function then translates empty input into the default choice.
- The selected choice is returned as a `1`-based *index* rather than the text. In other words: you can assume that a valid choice was made when the function returns, and that choice is indicated by its *position* among the choices given.

```
# Custom `select` implementation with support for a default choice
# that the user can make by pressing just ENTER.
# Pass the choices as individual arguments; e.g. `selectWithDefault Yes No``
# The first choice is the default choice, unless you designate
# one of the choices as the default with a leading '!', e.g.
# `selectWithDefault Yes !No`
# The default choice is printed with a trailing ' [default]'
# Output is the 1-based *index* of the selected choice, as shown
# in the UI.
# Example:
#    choice=$(selectWithDefault 'Yes|No|!Abort' )
selectWithDefault() {

  local item i=0 numItems=$# defaultIndex=0

  # Print numbered menu items, based on the arguments passed.
  for item; do         # Short for: for item in "$@"; do
    [[ "$item" == !* ]] && defaultIndex=$(( $i + 1)) && item="${item:1} [default]"
    printf '%s\n' "$((++i))) $item"
  done >&2 # Print to stderr, as `select` does.

  # Prompt the user for the index of the desired item.
  while :; do
    printf %s "${PS3-#? }" >&2 # Print the prompt string to stderr, as `select` does.
    read -r index
    # Make sure that the input is either empty or that a valid index was entered.
    [[ -z $index ]] && index=$defaultIndex && break  # empty input == default choice  
    (( index >= 1 && index <= numItems )) 2>/dev/null || { echo "Invalid selection. Please try again." >&2; continue; }
    break
  done

  # Output the selected *index* (1-based).
  printf $index

}
```

Sample call:

```
# Print the prompt message and call the custom select function,
# designating 'Abort' as the default choice.
echo "Include audits?"
ndx=$(selectWithDefault 'Yes' 'No', '!Abort')

case $ndx in
  1) echo "include";;
  2) echo "don't include";;
  3) echo "abort";;
esac
```

---

#### Optional reading: A more idiomatic version of your original code

Note: This code doesn't solve the problem, but shows more idiomatic use of the `select` statement; unlike the original code, this code re-displays the prompt if an invalid choice was made:

```
optionsAudits=("Yep" "Nope")
echo "Include audits (^C to abort)?"
select opt in "${optionsAudits[@]}"; do
    # $opt being empty signals invalid input.
    [[ -n $opt ]] || { echo "What's that? Please try again." >&2; continue; }
    break # a valid choice was made, exit the prompt.
done

case $opt in  # $opt now contains the *text* of the chosen option
  'Yep')
     includeAudits=true
     ;;
  'Nope') # could be just `*` in this case.
     includeAudits=false
     ;;
esac
```

Note:

- The `case` statement was moved out of the `select` statement, because the latter now guarantees that only valid inputs can be made.
- The `case` statement tests the *output variable* (`$opt`) rather than the raw user input (`$REPLY`), and that variable contains the choice *text*, not its *index*.

Comment: I hardly know where to start :) Could you explain the last line that is returning the selected value from the function?

Comment: `[[ -n $index ]]` tests the value of variable `$index` for "non-emptiness" (`-n`); if it is nonempty (i.e., has a value), then the RHS of the `&&` control operator is evaluated. `printf %s "${@: index:1}"` prints the positional parameter (argument) with index `$index`: `$@` is the array of all positional parameters (arguments passed to the function, i.e., the choices). Slicing syntax `${<array-var>[@] <index>:<length>}` extracts the element of interest. Note that special array `$@` - unlike regular Bash arrays - is _1_-based.

Comment: Could I pass the select options to the function as an array so that I could also pass to it which option is the default?

Comment: Without trickery you can't pass an array _as such_ to a function. Passing an array such as `"${optionsAudits[@]}"` (see my update) to the function actually passes its elements _as individual arguments_ (positional parameters). Adding a mechanism to designate the default element would complicate the function, and I'm not sure if it's worth doing. If you do want to tackle it: either designate the 1st or last positional parameter as the default value, or add a unique suffix to the default element to mark it as such (which the function would need to parse and remove).

Comment: Yes I see, seems like a difficult issue in bash. One more question: Why doesn't "echo" work inside this function? Why the need for the ">&2" in order to get things printed to stdout/stderr?

Comment: btw, ^C will abort the entire script.  The user can use ^D (or more generically, whatever `<EOF>` is on their terminal) to cause `select` to finish and go to the next line of the script with the output variable still empty.

Comment: If it's always the first option that's the default, how about having the function itself mark it?
`# mark default option with this string
local defstr="[default] "

# Print numbered menu items, based on the arguments passed.
for (( i=1; i<=$#; ++i )); do
    printf '%i) %s%s\n' $i "$defstr" "${@:$i:1}"
    defstr=""
done >&2`

Comment: @RL-S, moving the logic of translating empty input into a default choice into the function itself is a great idea, but I think that requires a mechanism that allows you to indicate _which_ choice should be the default, as it won't always be the first (in the original use case it is the second one). Please see my update: I've added an alternative implementation with such a mechanism.

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is due to the fact that `select` will ignore empty input. For your case, `read` will be more suitable, but you will lose the utility `select` provides for automated menu creation.

To emulate the behaviour of `select`, you could do something like that :

```
#!/bin/bash
optionsAudits=("Yep" "Nope")
while : #infinite loop. be sure to break out of it when a valid choice is made
do
    i=1
    echo "Include Audits?"
    #we recreate manually the menu here
    for o in  "${optionsAudits[@]}"; do
        echo "$i) $o"
        let i++
    done

    read reply
    #the user can either type the option number or copy the option text
    case $reply in
        "1"|"${optionsAudits[0]}") includeAudits=true; break;;
        "2"|"${optionsAudits[1]}") includeAudits=false; break;;
        "") echo "empty"; break;;
        *) echo "Invalid choice. Please choose an existing option number.";;
    esac
done
echo "choice : \"$reply\""
```

Comment: Instead of the cycle "for" you can use  as well this workabout: "echo foo | select foo in "${optionsAudits[@]}"; do break; done"  It produces more column menu, if you like...

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer:

```
echo "Include audits? 1) Yep, 2) Nope"
read ans
case $ans in
    Yep|1  )  echo "yes"; includeAudits=true; v=1 ;;
    Nope|2 )  echo "no"; includeAudits=false; v=2 ;;
    ""     )  echo "default - yes"; includeAudits=true; v=1 ;;
    *      )  echo "Whats that?"; exit ;;
esac
```

This accepts either `"Yep"` or `"1"` or `"enter"` to select yes, and accepts `"Nope"` or `"2"` for no, and throws away anything else.   It also sets v to 1 or 2 depending on whether the user wanted yes or no.

Comment: You haven't shown how to address a default value for `ans`.

Comment: @chepner, eh? `*)` handles the empty-string through the `*)` case, which is exactly what the OP asked for. Though it's not fully equivalent to `select`, since it doesn't write out a prompt or map numeric to string results, so there's certainly room for improvement/extension.

Comment: `*` handles *everything* other than `Yep` or `Nope`, including invalid inputs. This also doesn't actually assign a default value to `ans` if the empty string is, indeed, the input.

Comment: There's an exit after the `*)` which means that `$ans` doesn't get used after that... (which again, is what the OP was after...)

Comment: Added prompt as per @CharlesDuffy's comment.  I'm not sure OP was after the enumerated values, so I didn't add that.

Comment: Sorry my question was not so clear. I was looking for the same functionality as I posted (being able to choose "1" or "2") with an additional option to press enter, in which case I would myself select option 1 or 2 for the user.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that does change things.  You already have an answer, but I'll update mine anyways, in case it helps as well.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you are asking for.

```
options=("option 1" "option 2");
while :
do
    echo "Select your option:"
    i=1;
    for opt in  "${options[@]}"; do
        echo "$i) $opt";
        let i++;
    done

    read reply
    case $reply in
        "1"|"${options[0]}"|"")
          doSomething1();
          break;;
        "2"|"${options[1]}")
          doSomething2();
          break;;
        *)
          echo "Invalid choice. Please choose 1 or 2";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Your answer has a syntax error in it: 
`line 14: syntax error near unexpected token \`;'`
`line 14: \`          doSomething1();'` If you remove the `();` from lines 14 and 17, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your default option is `Yep`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
optionsAudits=("Yep" "Nope")
while : #infinite loop. be sure to break out of it when a valid choice is made
do
    i=1
    echo "Include Audits?: "
    #we recreate manually the menu here
    for o in  "${optionsAudits[@]}"; do
        echo "  $i) $o"
        let i++
    done

    read -rp "Audit option: " -iYep
    #the user can either type the option number or copy the option text
    case $REPLY in
        "1"|"${optionsAudits[0]}") includeAudits=true; break;;
        "2"|"${optionsAudits[1]}") includeAudits=false; break;;
        "") includeAudits=true; break;;
        *) echo "Invalid choice. Please choose an existing option number.";;
    esac
done
echo "choice : \"$REPLY\""
echo "includeAudits : \"$includeAudits\""
```

Noticed the line:

```sh
    read -rp "Audit option: " -eiYep
```

Also I pulled up `$reply` to `$REPLY` so that the case decision works better.

The output would now look like this upon hitting ENTER:

```
Include Audits?: 
  1) Yep
  2) Nope
Audit option: Yep
choice : ""
includeAudits : "true"
#
```

As an enhancement over `select`, `read -eiYep`  will supply `Yep` default value into the input buffer up front.

Only downside of fronting the default value is that one would have to press backspace a few times to enter in their own answer.