# How to update variable within case statement based on user input

Tags: linux, bash, unix, input, menu

I have created a bash script which is essentially a wizard with a number of questions, some are multiple choice. When a multiple choice question is presented, I want the user to be able to choose a number, where each number corresponds to a different answer. I want this answer to be the variable which can be later used in the script.

I realize this is what the 'select' function is used for, but I also have a requirement when the user simply hits [ENTER] a default value is assumed. As far as I know, the 'select' function assumes an empty value of "" when the [ENTER] key is pressed (an invalid option) and re-prompts the question.

The code below is me attempting to update a variable when a number is pressed. For example when the number '1' is pressed, I want the $hash variable to updated to 'sha224'.

Is there any to achieve this using a case statement without 'select'? If not what are my alternatives?

```
echo
echo "Select a hashing algorithm"
echo "1 - sha224"
echo "2 - sha256"
echo "3 - sha384"
echo "4 - sha512"
while true; do 
read -p "Option: [sha256]:" -e hash
    case $hash in
        "") hash="sha256" break 2;;
        1) hash="sha224" break 2;;
        2) hash="sha256" break 2;;
        3) hash="sha384" break 2;;
        4) hash="sha512" break 2;;
        *) echo "Invalid Response: Please enter [1-4] and hit [ENTER] or hit [ENTER] to select 'sha256'";;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Since Cyrus has already gave a correct answer, just one question from me out of curiosity: Why don't you want to use `select`? It seems to be the perfect command for this type of question.

Comment: Hi there... The only reason is I need to present the user with a default option, preferably by simply pressing Enter. It is not advised to use some options available in the multi-choice questions, unless you are absolutely sure you know what they are used for. This is where the default/already selected option.comes in handy. If you know of a way of achieving this with 'select', I would love to hear it!

Comment: @HazyMaze : Inside the body of your `select`, you can process what the user enters. If the user just hits return, you get an empty string in the reply. In this case you just set your selection to the default value, and execute a `break`.

Comment: @user1934428 - This doesn't work. When using `select`, it ignores `"") hash="sha256" break 2;;`. It seems this is by design - [bash: choose default from case when enter is pressed in a “select” prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42789273/bash-choose-default-from-case-when-enter-is-pressed-in-a-select-prompt/42790579#42790579)

Comment: You don't put the break there!!! Acutally, you don't have any parenthesis at all, because you don't have a `case` statement anymore. `select` basically combines what `while` and `case` is doing. And, if you say "this doesn't work", post the whole code which doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Insert `;` before all `break`.
- Replace `$hash` with `${hash:=2}` to use a default value if $hash is empty.
- `"") hash="sha256" break 2;;` can be removed.

Comment: Thanks so much. That did the trick! Wish I asked the question days ago. On the contrary, I learned a tonne of bash while trying to figure it out.